# Is it possible to use a specific class in the javafx Dialog?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

I was searching for javafx JOptionPane equivalent and I did found a great class the Dialog. So in the tutorial, the tutor used : `Dialog<Pair<String,String>>` to get two String input fields and from here I m wondering is it possible to use a class let say : `Dialog<Product>`. If is possible how should I write this class is their any specific pattern or plot to do so?
Thanks

Comment: this idea crossed my mind because I m already using adapter pattern between JAVAFX and JPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. My answer is basing on:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/dialog-javafx/javafx-dialog-example/

Assuming your Product has two fields which can be passed via constructor:

```
String name;
float price;
```

You can create your Dialog in such way:

```
Dialog<Product> dialog = new Dialog<>();
dialog.setTitle("Product Dialog");
dialog.setResizable(true);

Label nameLabel = new Label("Name: ");
Label priceLabel = new Label("Price: ");
TextField nameField = new TextField();
TextField priceField = new TextField();

GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.add(nameLabel, 1, 1);
grid.add(nameField, 2, 1);
grid.add(priceLabel, 1, 2);
grid.add(priceField, 2, 2);
dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

ButtonType saveButton = new ButtonType("Save", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(saveButton);

dialog.setResultConverter(new Callback<ButtonType, Product>() {
    @Override
    public Product call(ButtonType button) {
        if (button == saveButton) {
            String name = nameField.getText();
            Float price;
            try {
                price = Float.parseFloat(priceField.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Add some log or inform user about wrong price
                return null;
            }

            return new Product(name, price);
        }

        return null;
    }
});

Optional<Product> result = dialog.showAndWait();

if (result.isPresent()) {
    Product product = result.get();
    // Do something with product
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, because if the external URL goes away, your answer is of no use to future readers.  Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: thanks, I will try to encapsulate this answer for a better future use